# Сортировка двумерного массива php по сумме значений

Tags: php, сортировка

Помогите найти решение задачи на php.
Есть массив след. вида `[key => [key => value]]`
Для понимания 1 ключ название услуги, второй ключ даты, значение это сумма покупки в эту дату. название `[услуги => [05-05-2018 => 500]]`

Необходимо отсортировать данный массив по общей сумме покупок каждой из услуг.

В итоге должен получиться массив, в сохраненном виде, но первые ключи с названием услуг, должны идти в порядке убывания итоговой суммы по данной услуге за все дни.

Comment: приведите конкретный пример исходного массива и желаемого результата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если подразумевается, что ключей с датами может быть несколько, то есть следующий вид исходных данных:

```
$data = [
    'test1' => ['a' => 100, 'b' => 100],
    'test2' => ['c' => 50],
    'test3' => ['d' => 500],
];
```

То вам поможет функция сортировки `uasort()` и суммирования `array_sum()`:

```
uasort($data, function($l,$r){ return array_sum($r) - array_sum($l);});

print_r(array_keys($data));
```

результат будет

```
Array (
    [0] => test3
    [1] => test1
    [2] => test2
)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Все работает, а не могли бы пояснить принцип работы, чтобы я впредь мог сам решить подобные задачи

Comment: @МихаилЧижиков а что конкретно вам тут не ясно? `uasort` сортирует массив используя пользовательскую функцию сравнения. При любой сортировке ф-я сравнения получает на вход два сравниваемых элемента и возвращает целочисленный результат. Если результат = 0, то элементы равны. Если нет, то соответственно больше или меньше. В зависимости от этого ф-я сортировки меняет местами элементы.  
Здесь на вход попадают вложенные массивы. А сравнивать нам надо сумму их элементов.